# regular expression does not replace hyphens with dots

Tags: python, regex

For the following text:

```
comment = """ I took the pill -  I realized only side-effect after I went off it how it affected my eating habits - I put on weight - around 10 lbs - in the 2.5 months on it - no control and syndrome - this was counterproductive !"""
```

I wrote regular expression to `replace hyphen (-) with dot (.)`

```
comment = re.sub (r'(w+\s+)(-)(\s+\w+)', r'\1\. \3 ', comment )
```

But it does not work.

I do not want the hyphen between two words such as side-effect replace with dot. 
thats why I cannot use `comment.replace ('-', '.')`

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: You have a typo in the regex, use [`(\w+\s+)(-)(\s+\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mP2xSH/1)

Comment: .... and there's no need to escape dot in substitution string

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you very much !

Comment: However, I do not think you actually need so many whitespaces after dash removal. What about a [`re.sub(r'\b\s+-\s+\b', ' - ', comment)`](https://regex101.com/r/mP2xSH/3)?

Comment: Would the "-" to be replaced by dot be always surrounded by space? If thats the case .replace(' - ',' . ') should work where "-" is preceded and followed by space.

Comment: @Sid, yes it always surrounded by space

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `str.replace` method

```
comment.replace('-', '...')
```

Comment: UV for not using a bazooka to swat a fly (that's a french expression, I hope you get it) and for thinking outside the box.

Comment: @Patrick Haung, But your solution will replace hyphen with dot in some words, for example: "side-effect". I do not want this happen.

Comment: @Mary if you're only looking for hyphen surrounded by spaces then replace `'-'` with `' - '` in the above